# end consumer thread after producer thread and consuming all the elements

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have written code to implement producer consumer problem using wait and notify. It is working fine but the problem is consumer thread is running in an infinite loop and keeps on waiting even after producer thread has finished and consumer has consumed all the elements from list.

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(empList , 2) , "Producer");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(empList , 2) , "Consumer");

        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }

}

class Employee 
{
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
class Producer implements Runnable 
{
    List<Employee> empList; 
    int size;

    public Producer(final List<Employee> empList  , final int size)
    {
        this.empList = empList;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override    
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
        {
            try {
                produce(new Employee());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void produce(Employee e) throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized(empList){
            while(empList.size()==size) // If list is full then will have to wait
            {

                System.out.println("List is full "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Is waiting and" + " Size is "+empList.size());
                empList.wait();
            }
        }

        synchronized(empList)
        {
            System.out.println("Producing");
            empList.add(e);
            empList.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}


class Consumer implements Runnable 
{
    List<Employee> empList; 
    int size;

    public Consumer(final List<Employee> empList  , final int size)
    {
        this.empList = empList;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override    
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumed ");
                consume();
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized(empList){
            while(empList.isEmpty()) // If list is empty then will have to wait
            {
                System.out.println("List is empty "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Is waiting and " + "Size is "+empList.size());
                empList.wait();
            }
        }

        synchronized(empList)
        {
            empList.notifyAll();
            empList.remove(0);
        }

    }    

}
```

Kindly tell me how can I stop my consumer thread after producer finishes and consumer has consumed all the elements from list. Please help me with the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know when producer finishes?

Comment: @PM77-1 After execution of run method of producer it ends because it loops only 5 times. After consuming all the elements consumer gives up its lock and wait for any notification to come but no notification comes thus it keeps on waiting. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: So you want consumer to time out?

Comment: yes... but only after producer finishes and consumption of all the elements.

Comment: You can't predict that the consumer start working after producer done looping. Once you start both the threads may run parallel. You cannot make a prediction when producer ends producing unless you make it sequential. If you make it sequential there is no need of locking or using separate threads.

Comment: How would consumer know producer is done and not merely slow?

Comment: @PM77-1 I think i got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just add flag, shared between producer and consumer:

```
static bool producerFinished = false;
```

Set it in the producer after it produce all elements:

```
public void run()
{
    // ...
    synchronized(empList){
        producerFinished = true;
        empList.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

And check it in the consumer's while() loop alongside with list emptiness

```
public void consume()
{
    synchronized(empList){
        while(empList.isEmpty() && !producerFinished)
        {
            empList.wait();
        }

        if(!empList.isEmpty())
        {
            //consume element
        }
        else
        {
            //List is empty and producer has finished.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, `producerFinished` should be declared `volatile`.

Comment: @tariksbl: Because this flag is accessed *under lock taken*, it doesn't require to be declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

A producer-consumer idiom for this is the Poison Pill pattern:  the producer puts a magic value in the queue when finished producing, then quits.  When the consumer reads the magic value, it quits.

Poison pill definition is shared between producer and consumer:

```
static final Employee POISON_PILL = new Employee();
```

Producer:

```
public void run()
{
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        produce(new Employee());
    }
    produce(POISON_PILL);
}
```

Consumer:

```
public void consume() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized(empList){
        while(empList.isEmpty())
        {
            empList.wait();
        }
    }

    synchronized(empList)
    {
        // Note == not .equals() is intended here
        if (empList.remove(0) == POISON_PILL) {
            // done consuming
        }
        empList.notifyAll();
    }

}
```